# How to check fromElement/toElement in mouse event?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a tooltip using JavaScript. Part of my script has function for debugging purposes:

```
function fnTooltip(e) {
    if (e.type === "mouseout") {
        console.log(...);
        if ((e.fromElement === "td") && (e.toElement !== "td")) {
            debugger;
            console.log(...);
        }
    }
}
```

When i move mouse out from td cell, nothing happens. If i write to console "e.fromElement" and "e.toElement", they both are equal "[object HTMLTableCellElement]". In another part of my script using almost the same function but with event type "mouseover", everything works fine. So what am i doing wrong? How do i check e.fromElelement and e.toElement.
I also tried relatedTarget, target, srcTarget with same result.

Comment: Checking an HTML element _object_ against a literal ("td") will never yield true. What you want to do instead, is to compare the `nodeName` property of the object to whether it is "td" or not.

Comment: Shame on me (( I used tagName property before. Thanks @CBroe